# Remove company name in android package

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

A while back I created a phonegap android app and put it on the google play store with the package name com.packagename I have since rebuilt the app in native code using android studio. Having just tried to update the app on google play and found that the package name does not match because android studio adds a company section i.e. com.companyname.packagename

I have tried refactoring but there does not seem to be a way to remove the companyname section. Is there anyway to do this? I am assuming there is no way around this in google play?

Comment: What is your company name?  Are you sure you don't want to keep that?  It's done this way to ensure absolute uniqueness.

Comment: I am just using my name at the moment. I would prefer to keep it but the problem is that the app I originally uploaded to google play did not have this and so I can't see a way to add this now. Actually it might be that my original app had a company name and not a package name but that would both look the same (I cant remember the details of the original app as this was over a year ago).

Comment: If everything else fails, use Eclipse.  It doesn't require any format for the packagename.  And if Android Studio does its yet another reason not to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway to do this?

Go into `build.gradle` and delete `companyname` from the `applicationId` values. Then, double-check your `AndroidManifest.xml` file and delete `companyname` from the `package` attribute in the root `<manifest>` element.

Comment: I tried doing this but get a load of problems with R.java not existing. I tried rebuilding but it wont work without refactoring in the file tree which wont allow a null input - back to square one

Comment: Ah ha. I just needed to follow your instructions and then manually change each class's package name and then move the class in to a new directory. Uploaded and working!